# Issues trying to integrate ActiveMQ v5.4.3 to JBoss v 4.0.5

Tags: java, integration, activemq-classic, jboss-4.0.x

I am trying to integrate `ActiveMQ v5.4.3` with `Jboss v4.0.5` using [Integrate ActiveMQ with Jboss](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ACTIVEMQ/Integrating+Apache+ActiveMQ+with+JBoss) and [ActiveMQ Jboss Integration](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/IntegratingActiveMQWithJBoss) but it is not working and am getting following errors:

```
    2011-12-07 10:54:45,042 [main] ERROR org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner - Incomplete Deployment listing:

--- Packages waiting for a deployer ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@a3aa0ff2 { url=file:/C:/Users/workspace/mdi-trunk/devel/platform/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/node/deploy/activemq-rar-5.4.3/ }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/Users/workspace/mdi-trunk/devel/platform/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/node/deploy/activemq-rar-5.4.3/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1323273285039
  lastModified: 1323209490284
  mbeans:

--- Incompletely deployed packages ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@a3aa0ff2 { url=file:/C:/Users/workspace/mdi-trunk/devel/platform/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/node/deploy/activemq-rar-5.4.3/ }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/Users/workspace/mdi-trunk/devel/platform/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/node/deploy/activemq-rar-5.4.3/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1323273285039
  lastModified: 1323209490284
  mbeans:

--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=TxCM,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory
    jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager
    jboss:service=TransactionManager
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionFactory,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=TxCM,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionFactory,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq-ra.rar'
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=TxCM,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=TxCM,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory
    jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager
    jboss:service=TransactionManager
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionFactory,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=TxCM,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionFactory,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq-ra.rar'
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionPool,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=TxCM,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory

ObjectName: activemq.queue:name=outboundQueue
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq-ra.rar'

ObjectName: activemq.topic:name=inboundTopic
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq-ra.rar'

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq-ra.rar'
  State: NOTYETINSTALLED
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionFactory,name=activemq/QueueConnectionFactory
    jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionFactory,name=activemq/TopicConnectionFactory
    activemq.queue:name=outboundQueue
    activemq.topic:name=inboundTopic
```

I have deployed `activemq-ra.rar` in jboss deploy directory and so I am not sure why it is not working, i would really appreciate any pointers or suggestions to  move forward.

Thanks.

**Update**
I was able to get it up and running, i had very silly issue, folder name where my activemq-ra.rar was specified as activemq-ra.1.2.2.rar and so jboss was not able to recognize it while starting up the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may very well be because you're using a pretty old version of JBoss (4.0.x) with a newer version of ActiveMQ (5.4.x). JBoss is now at version 7, and they've changed ALOT of things in the mean time (the micro container alone has been completly re written). Also, the article you're following is pretty old, as it reffers to JBoss 4.x and ActiveMQ 4.0.1. My recommandation is to either follow that article and use the exact version of each as mentioned there or to use the latest JBoss and Active MQ and try to update the instructions with more recent documentation, such as the things discussed in this thread: http://community.jboss.org/thread/172319

Comment: Migrating to latest version of Jboss is in the pipeline but mean while do you know why am getting the mentioned error. My producer is able to populate ActiveMQ queue with the messages and all am trying to do is get my `message driven bean` to listen on queue and get messages out and having issues with it.

Comment: Well yes, but even so (even if some of your compnents work), the error message clearly sais (IMHO) that the ActiveMQ JBoss arhive (RAR) is not correctly installed (ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='activemq-ra.rar'State: NOTYETINSTALLED). If you're just trying a proofOfConcept you should try using jboss 4 and activemq 4 as per the instructions on the activemq page. I've had issues like this one, where something made for version x of jboss didn't work for version x+1.

Comment: Hmm...the thing is am able to populate messages into ActiveMQ v5.4.3 and so didn't wanted to start again from ground and make modifications.

Comment: Well, i'm sorry to say that I've arrived at the end of my knowledge on this. However, to encourage you to try newer version, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727026/embed-activemq-into-jboss-7. This person has used the same guide and succeeded in installing ActiveMq 5.5 with Jboss 5...